# {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

Tags: python, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I try to use Twitter API via Python. I use oauth library and update function.

The code is:

```
oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=twitter_settings.access_token_key, secret=twitter_settings.access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=twitter_settings.consumer_key, secret=twitter_settings.consumer_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

def twitter_req(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=http_method,
                                             http_url=url, 
                                             parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  print encoded_post_data
  print url
  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response

update_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
update_parameters = {'status': "test"}    

update_response = twitter_req(update_url, "POST", update_parameters)
```

I get this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

I spend hours to try to find the answer in the internet, but I couldn't. Please help.

Comment: I have the same issue, how you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your OAuth signature.

Note the change in `http_method=method` not `http_method=http_method`

```
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=method,
                                             http_url=url, 
                                             parameters=parameters)
```

You may also find [this page helpful](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses) to explain what the error codes mean.